# Monitor Oracle DB with Zabbix

Tags: zabbix, unixodbc

I install and configure Oracle instant client and unixODBC. When login with `root`, can connect to db by sqlplus or isql.

```
root@zabbix:~# sqlplus ***/***@***

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Tue Mar 7 13:56:42 2017
Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Last Successful login time: Tue Mar 07 2017 13:19:45 +03:00
Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL>

root@zabbix:~# isql ***
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL>
```

But in Zabbix admin panel I got error `Cannot connect to ODBC DSN:[SQL_ERROR]:[08004][12154][[unixODBC][Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified]|`.

I think this is trouble with no exists env for zabbix user, because `sudo -u zabbix env` output not contain `ORACLE_HOME, TNS_ADMIN, NLS_LANG` etc.

Where I can set it or what a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem.

1. Create file `/etc/default/zabbix-server` with necessary variables:

   `ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64
   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib
   NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_CIS.CL8MSWIN1251
   TNS_ADMIN=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/network/admin`
2. Restart Zabbix server
3. Get main PID of Zabbix server process and check process env with `strings -a /proc/18253/environ` (replace 18253 with your PID):

   `LANG=en_US.UTF-8
   PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
   CONFFILE=/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
   ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64
   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib
   NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_CIS.CL8MSWIN1251
   TNS_ADMIN=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/network/admin`