# ERROR monitoring oracle by odbc in zabbix : Can't open lib '/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libsqora.so.12.1'

Tags: oracle, odbc, monitoring, oracle12c, zabbix

I install ODBC to monitoring Oracle Database via Zabbix, but I got error :

Can't open lib '/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libsqora.so.12.1'

I did everything on tutorial, here's my config :

/etc/odbcinst.ini :

```
[OracleDriver]
Description=Oracle ODBC driver for Oracle 12g
Driver=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libsqora.so.12.1
```

/etc/odbc.ini :

```
[PEWDS]
Driver= OracleDriver
DSN= ROLF
ServerName= ROLF
UserID= zabbix
Password= zabbix
```

tnsnames.ora :

```
ROLF =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = XXX.XXX.XXX)(PORT = 1539))
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = EXAMPLE)
)
)
```

However when i try to connect isql with

```
 isql -v PEWDS
```

it works and connect to isql

I try to follow [this step too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42646564/monitor-oracle-db-with-zabbix), from that step I should make **/etc/default/zabbix-server** that contain oracle home, ld library path, nls lang, and tns admin. then I have to restart zabbix-server and do this command **strings -a /proc/(pid number)/environ**, but it doesn't solve my problem..

I try to make **/etc/sysconfig/zabbix-server** too but when i restart zabbix server i got error that zabbix server is ignoring invalid environment assignment

can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add path to library in  `ld.so.conf`

```
sudo sh -c "echo /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/ > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-client.conf"
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: it solved the problem "Can't open lib '/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libsqora.so.12.1" thanks, but I got new error.. TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified. 

Apparently oracle 12c use port 1539 but zabbix is looking for port 1521, I already change listener port from 1539 to 1521 in Oracle database.. can you help me again? thanks..

is there any other way to make zabbix looking for port 1521?

Comment: You need to add `$TNS_ADMIN=/path_to_tnsname.ora_directory` to zabbix user's environment variables. For example $TNS_ADMIN=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/network/admin

Comment: Check read permissions for file tnsnmanes.ora for user zabbix.